# django - dynamic field's verbose_name/label

Tags: python, django

i am searching for the right way to implement the same model data but with different fields titles corresponding to the group the user belong to.

for example:
if the model field name is "text",
for group1 admin will define that the verbose_name/label = "text1",
so:
1. when the model form open for update "text1" will be showen.

2. make the fields headers of the table (at the templates) that shows a model list result by the same behavior.

and of course solution with good performance and cost.

would much appreaciate some guidence,
thanks